# Finding components of lines intersecting at a point.

Tags: coordinate-systems

I'm just working on some summer problems so that I can be more prepared when I go into my class in the fall. I found a website full of problems of the content we will be learning but it doesn't have the answers. I need a little guidance on how to do this problem. Here is the problem:

Consider the lines $L1$ and $L2$ with equations:

$L_1 : r = (11, 8, 2) + s(4, 3, -1)$
$L_2 : r = (1, 1,-7) + t(2, 1, 11)$
The lines intersect at point $P$.

a. Find the coordinates of $P$.
Would we use a formula for this? For example: $\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}, \frac{y_1+y_2}{2}, \frac{z_1+z_2}{2}$.

b. Show that the lines are perpendicular.
Isn’t there also a formula to find if lines are perpendicular?

Comment: Do you mean $(11,8,2)+s(4,3,-1)?$

Comment: @mfl The question I found says -1, not -2. But, perhaps there was an error on their part. I am not sure.

Comment: Sorry about the $-2$. I mean the way you write the line. It is written as [11, 8, 2] + s = [4, 3, -1]

Comment: @mfl Oh, yes! You’re right. Thank you. Just fixed it.

Comment: I don't understand c. $R$ is the reflection of $Q$ with respect to what?

Comment: @Ella Check the latest edit to make sure it matches the way the problem was presented to you. The way mfl changed your equations is a way the formula for a line is often represented. What you had before did not make sense as the equations of lines: $r = (11, 8, 2) + s = (4, 3, -1)$ implies that $r = (4,3,-1),$ because equality is transitive, so you really just had written equations for two single points.

Comment: The results from parts a and b make c particularly easy to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying that 
$L_1:r=(11,8,2)+s(4,3,−1)$
means that every point on the line is of the form
(x, y, z)= (11+ 4s, 8+ 3s, 2- s) for some number s.
In other words, x= 11+ 4s, y= 8+ 3s, z= 2- s.

$L_2:r=(1,1,−7)+t(2,1,11)$
means that every point on the line is of the form
(x, y, z)= (1+ 2t, 1+ t, -7+ 11t) for some number t.
In other words, x= 1+ 2t, y= 1+ t, z= -7+ 11t.

Where the two lines intercept the x, y, z coordinates must be the same: 11+ 4s= 1+ 2t, 8+ 3s= 1+ t, 2- s= -7+ 11t.

Notice that these are **three** equations in only two unknowns, s and t.  In general, two lines in three dimensions do NOT intersect- most often they are "skew".  What we can do is solve two of the equations for s and t then see if those s and t satisfy the third equation.
11+ 4s= 1+ 2t is the same as 10+ 4s= 2t or 5+ 2s= t.  Setting t= 5+ 2s in the second equation, 8+ 3s= 1+ t= 6+ 2s.  s= -2 and then t= 5- 4= 1.

Checking the third equation, 2- s= -7+ 11t, 2- (-2)= 4= -7+ 11.  Yes, those values are the same so the lines intersect at x= 11+ 4(-2)= 11- 8= 3, y= 8+ 3s= 8+ 3(-2)= 8- 6= 2, z= 2- s= 2- (-2)= 4.  The two lines intersect at P= (3, 2, 4).

Answer (score 0):

**Ideas to get the answer**

**Part a):**

You need to solve the system

\begin{align}
11+4s&=1+2t\\
8+3s&=1+t\\
2-s&=-7+11t
\end{align}

**Part b):**

The lines are perpendicular if and only if its directions are perpendicular. That is, if and only if $$(4,3,-1)\cdot (2,1,11)=0.$$

Comment: For part a, would I combine like terms and solve for both s and t?

Comment: Yes. Note that if $(x,y,z)$ is the intersection point then it must be $x=11+4s$ (line 1) and $x=1+2t$ (line 2). The same for $y,z.$ Once you get a solution of the system ($s,t$ must be a solution of the $3$ equations) you substitute $s$ in the first line (or $t$ in the second line) and you'll get $P$.